# What is this plot called and how to make it in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Suppose I have a graph like this

```
plot(np.random.rand(10))
pylab.ylim([-0,1.5])
```

[image]

and I have a state sequence as such

```
In[141]:np.random.randint(5,size=(1, 10))
Out[142]:array([[2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 4]])
```

I want to superimpose that state sequence on the above plot like this:

[image: State sequence example superimposed on data.]

But how does one do this in matplotlib?

To summarise: I want different parts of your plot to have differently coloured background that depends on the state, where each unique state has a unique colour.

Comment: You want different parts of your plot to have differently colored background that shows the state. Is that a correct interpretation?

Comment: Yes exactly; states that are the same have the same colour, so all in all, states should have a unique colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To divide your plot into differently colored sections you can use the [`axvspan`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axvspan) function.

This requires that you know the x-coordinate boundaries for your states.
Assuming that a state is always `L` units long, and that `STATE_COLOR` is a mapping between state number and a matplotlib color ('r', 'k', 'b', ...) then you get the following:

```
# States and their colors
state_list = [1, 2, 1]
STATE_COLOR = { 1 : 'r', 2 : 'y' }

L = 1.5 # Constant state length

x = np.linspace(0, 4.5)
y = x**2 - 3

# Draw states
for i, state in enumerate(state_list):
    x1 = i * L
    x2 = (i+1) * L
    plt.axvspan(x1, x2, color=STATE_COLOR[state])

# Draw line data
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Comment: Ah not bad at all! But should it really be this complicated? I was under the impression that this was a fairly standard procedure. If I have several hundred different states, then they will require manual coding of a corresponding state colour.

Comment: You could pick the color from one of the builtin colormaps. If you have several hundreds of states then you might have to keep an eye out for repeating colors. You could also make sure to plot the boundaries with a vertical line using `axvline` to make sure that even if two states have the same color and are adjacent they will still be distingusihable.